# How to fill the text boxes based on the value of select box options in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form like this

```
<form >
<select name = "person">
  <option name ="first" value= "first">@$_SESSION['person']</optio>
  .
  .
  .
 </select>
```

and two text boxes

```
<input type="text" name = "name" value ="" >
<input type ="text" name ="address" value= "">
</form>
```

Please explain with syntax ,how to fill the text boxes base on the option selected in the drop down list.

Comment: it has to fill with the name and address of session variable $['person'.$i].$['name'] and $['person.$i].$['address']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have it done without a page reload this is the code:

```
<select name="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('myTextBoxAddress').value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.indexOf('_')); document.getElementById('myTextBoxName').value = this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf('_') + 1, this.value.length);">
 <option value="<?=$_SESSION[0]['addr'] . '_' . $_SESSION[0]['name'];?>"><?=$_SESSION[0]['name'];?></option>
 <option value="<?=$_SESSION[1]['addr'] . '_' . $_SESSION[1]['name'];?>"><?=$_SESSION[1]['name'];?></option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myTextBoxAddress" value="" />
<input type="text" id="myTextBoxName" value="" />
```

I put both the address and the name values in the value of the options seperated by a '_'. In the onchange i divided the value string again and filled the inputs with them.

Comment: im not such a fan of multiple lines of javascript in my html, but for a one time use it will have to do.

Comment: i used short tags in this example. If your php doesn't work, you could try to replace all <?= to <?php echo .

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is dynamic with javascript or jquery so you don't have to reload the page. like this:

```
<select name="mySelect" onchange="document.getElementById('myTextBox').value = this.value">
 <option value="first">first</option>
 <option value="second">second</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myTextBox" value="" />
```

Comment: This is a good start, but will not populate the data that @Vinay is looking for.

Comment: OK. If you want it done dynamically, the best way is to include the session data in the value of your options. Hold on, i think its best to make a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="person" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="Peter">@$_SESSION['person']</option>
.
.
.
</select>

<input type="text" name = "name" value ="<?php echo $_POST['person'] ?>" >
```

This would echo the value Peter

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

you need a function to get person data when you sumbit the person id to it and return it as an object to use it and the options of the "select" tag should hold the person id as value
like this :

```
<select name="person" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option name ="first" value= "first">@$_SESSION['person']</option>
       .
       .
       .
    </select>

<input type="text" name = "name" value ="<?php echo $person->name ?>" >
<input type ="text" name ="address" value= "<?php echo $person->address?>">
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are getting at here. Your sample code will also not work.